# Removing dot after Chapter number in thesis

Tags: formatting

I need to make correction in my PhD Thesis.
It asks me to remove Dot from chapter number in my thesis..

Below given is the code of thesis.tex file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{isuthesis}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{isutraditional}   \chaptertitle
\alternate
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\tracingpatches
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{~~~#1}{\\ \MakeUppercase{#1}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\section}{\centering\large\bfseries}
{\large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.jpg,.pdf,.mps,.png}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{chap1}
\end{document}
```

Below is the code of chap1.tex

```
\chapter{INTRODUCTION}

In distributed systems such as information systems and distributed shared 
memory (DSM) systems, data is either locally available or must be hauled
```

The output gives Chapter number with a dot at end. My reviewer has asked me to remove that. Plz help.

Comment: According to this example, there is a dot after chapter number. http://www.itlearningpods.com/Latex/isuthesiscomplete/thesis.pdf

Comment: That first `\patchcmd`-command in your preamble seems to be there to replace the hard-coded dot in the definition of chapter in `isutraditional.sty` on lines 94–105.

Comment: I dont want dot after Chapter 1

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems from the `isutraditional.sty`-package you are loading, where the dot is part of the definition of the `\@makechapterhead`-command. The command `\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{~~~#1}{\\ \MakeUppercase{#1}}{}{}` is the only thing you need to adjust slightly in your document. If you add a dot at the beginning of the string `\patchcmd` searches for, it will delete that dot for you.¹

```
\documentclass[12pt]{isuthesis}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{isutraditional}   \chaptertitle
\alternate
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\tracingpatches
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{.~~~#1}{\\ \MakeUppercase{#1}}{}{}%that dot right there (.~~~#1)
\patchcmd{\section}{\centering\large\bfseries}
{\large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.jpg,.pdf,.mps,.png}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{chap1}
\end{document}
```

¹ `\patchcmd` looks for the definition of a command, searches the string given in the second pair of curly brackets in that definition, and replaces it with the code in the third set of curly brackets.

As an aside: the comments in the .sty and .cls files are fun to read.